# stylelint - How to validate CSS within Custom XML file

Tags: css, xml, lint, stylelint

I have a set of `xml` files which stores the `CSS` syntax in `<CSS>` section of the file.

I want [stylelint](https://stylelint.io/) to validate that CSS within those files.

However, when I run the command `npx stylelint /**/*.xml` it gives no errors even if there are errors.

I tried using
`.stylelintrc.json`

```
{
    "extends": ["stylelint-config-standard"],
    "overrides": [{
        "files": ["*.xml"],
        "customSyntax": "postcss-html"
    }]
}
```

Is there any way to validate CSS inside the custom tag of the XML file?

TIA.